# Significance of the matrix representation of a bilinear form on a vector space as a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have a bilinear form $Q: V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ for a vector space $V$, then once we choose a basis for $V$ we can represent $Q$ as a matrix $M$ and then $Q(v_1,v_2)=v_1^tMv_2$. I was just wondering what the significance of the matrix representation of $Q$ is as a linear map on $V$. I mean, since $Q$ has a matrix form $M$ we can calculate $Q \cdot v = Mv$ for all $v \in V$

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $Q:V\times V\to \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: yeah what I said was correct, codomain should be $V$

Comment: @H Apparently I misread your question. Note that a bilinear map with codomain $V$ cannot be naturally represented as a matrix.

Comment: Oops, wow, I need mean $Q$ goes into the base field, i'm sorry >.<

Comment: So correct the question, please

Comment: done, sorry I forgot to haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$M$ is a matrix that represents the map $T:V \to V^*$ defined by
$$
T(v)(w) = Q(w,v).
$$

Note that to have a matrix representation of $Q$, we must first select a basis $\mathcal B = \{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ of $V$. Relative to this basis, the entries of $M$ are $m_{ij} = Q(e_i,e_j)$. Let $\mathcal B^* = \{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ denote the canonical "dual basis" of $\mathcal B$ to $V^*$, which is defined so that $f_i(e_j) = \delta_{ij}$.

We find that for any $e_j$ and $w = w_1e_1 + \cdots + w_ne_n \in V$, we have
$$
T(e_j)(w) = Q(w,e_i) = w_1Q(e_1,e_j) + \cdots + w_nQ(e_n,e_j)
\\= Q(e_1,e_j)f_1(w) + \cdots + Q(e_n,e_j)f_n(w)
\\ = [m_{1j} f_1 + \cdots + m_{nj}f_j](w),
$$
So that we have $T(e_j) = \sum_{i} m_{ij} f_j$, which means that $M$ is indeed the matrix of the transformation $T$ relative to bases $\mathcal B, \mathcal B^*$.